# Is there a more pythonic way of combining duplicate objects in a list?

Tags: python

I have a list of objects.  Each object is a unique instance, consisting of any combinations of names and values.  I want to combine objects with duplicate names into a new instance of the same class, whose value is a list of the values of all duplicates.  This is my very non-pythonic approach:

```
def normalise_repeatable_options(options):
    flat = {}
    for o in options:
        if isinstance(o, Option):
            flat.setdefault(o.long, []).append(o)

    # Ensure options stay in the order they were prescribed.
    parsed = []
    for o in options:
        if isinstance(o, Option):
            dups = flat.get(o.long)
            if dups:
                parsed.append(Option.combine(*tuple(dups)))
                del flat[o.long]
        else:
            parsed.append(o)

    return parsed
```

*Update: The input and expected output from the function*

```
input = [
    Option('-f', '--filter', 1, 'merge file'),
    Option('-f', '--filter', 1, 'merge anotherfile'),
    Argument(None, 'a'),
    Argument(None, 'b'),
    Argument(None, 'c')
]

output = [
    Option('-f', '--filter', 1, ['merge file', 'merge anotherfile']),
    Argument(None, 'a'),
    Argument(None, 'b'),
    Argument(None, 'c')
]
```

I have also included the `Object.combine` class method, just in case you wondered what that does:

```
@classmethod
def combine(class_, *opts):
    t = opts[0]
    if len(opts) == 1: return t
    return class_(t.short, t.long, t.argcount, [o.value for o in opts])
```

Comment: Possible to provide sample input / output?

Comment: Which one of the `option` input is `o.long`?

Comment: The long option `--filter`.

Comment: Is the order of the Option/Argument objects in the output important?

Comment: Yes.  They must be in the same order (apart from the case where duplicates have been normalised).  The order of the normalised values must reflect the order of appearance of the repeated options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without being able to test, about about something like this?

```
def normalise_repeatable_options(options):
    parsed = []
    flat = defaultdict(list)

    for o in options:
        if isinstance(o, Option):
            # For the first instance of this object, add a placemarker
            if o.long not in flat:
                parsed.append(o.long)

            flat[o.long].append(o)
        else:
            parsed.append(o)

    return [Option.combine(*tuple(flat[o])) if isinstance(o, str) else o for o in parsed]
```

This way, you build your `parsed` list, leave placemarkers for the `Option` objects to be replaced.  I'm assuming that none of the objects in your input list are of type `str`.

Comment: In the `return` statement, where is `o` defined?

Comment: Made a small change.  Pinched the defaultdict idea from @hughbrown

Comment: Yes, that was certainly a better approach.  Though unpacking the list as I did should work just as well as unpacking the tuple, unless I'm missing something.  But whatever works.

Comment: I don't understand this answer. If `parsed` is a `defaultdict(list)`, how can you `append` to it? You need a `(key, value)` pair, and I see only a `value`. Does this code work? A naive reading says no. I think `flat` should be the `defaultdict`.

Comment: @hughdbrown Because `flat` is supposed to be the `defaultdict` - I didn't catch it after @Craig made that edit.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can start here:

```
from collections import defaultdict

def normalise_repeatable_options(options):
    actual_options = [o for o in options if isinstance(o, Option)]
    non_options = [o for o in options if not isinstance(o, Option)]

    flat = defaultdict(list)
    for o in actual_options:
        flat[o.long].append(o)

    parsed = (
        # Make list of the non-options plus ...
        non_options +

        # a flattened lists of Options plus ...
        [Option.combine(*tuple(dups)) for dup in flat.values() if len(dup) > 1] +

        # a list of Options
        [value[0] for value in flat.values() if len(value) == 1]
    )
    return parsed
```

Comment: I like the use of `defaultdict(list)`.  I have marked up for that.

Answer (score 0):

Try list comprehension :)

Not sure if this will work in your case, as I modify your code based on simple mapping of one code to another.

You get the flat by check isinstance, so you don't have to check it again.

There may be small errors in this code:

```
def normalise_repeatable_options(options):
    flat = {}
    parsed = []
    [flat.setdefault(o.long, []).append(o) if isinstance(o, Option)
     else parsed.append(o) for o in options]

    [parsed.append(Option.combine(*tuple(lst))) if len(lst) > 1 
     else parsed.append(lst) for lst in flat.values()]

    return parsed
```

Comment: *`combine`, not `combined`.

Comment: If you iterate `flat.values()`, won't that reorder the values based on their owner's hashed `long` attribute?

Comment: @Craig To my memory, order is preserved in values() or items(), but not in itervalues() or iteritems().